# Delphi Error E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Tags: delphi, console, indy

I used TStringList and something that looks like:

```
geo: TStringList;
response: TStringStream;
  begin
  http:=tidhttp.Create(nil);
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    geo:=TStringList.Create;
    response:=TStringStream.Create('');
    geo.Add('name=stas');
    geo.Add('pass=431');
    s:=http.Get('http://test.me');
    writeln(http.ResponseText);
    writeln(s);
    s:=http.Post('http://test.me',geo,response);
```

but something is wrong.  For example when I run it it's alerting with the error `[[DCC Error] consoleHttp.dpr(29): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter']` in `s:=http.Post('http://test.me',geo,response)`.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: exactly, it is no need to use third parametr.

Comment: It seems he might think that the geo stuff is some http-headers and response is the response?

Answer (score 5):

This error means which you are passing wrong parameters to the method `TIdHTTP.post`. this method  has several overloads

```
function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdStrings): string; overload;
function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdStream): string; overload;
function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream): string; overload;
procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream; AResponseContent: TIdStream); overload;
procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdStrings; AResponseContent: TIdStream); overload;
procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource, AResponseContent: TIdStream); overload;
```

but none match with the parameters which you are passing.

Answer (score 4):

do this:

```
http.Post('http://test.me',geo,response);
```

instead of:

```
s:=http.Post('http://test.me',geo,response);
```

The only matching method is a procedure, but procedures don't return values. The error message is saying that you can't assign a procedure to a string.